# Creating Git Rebase Alias

Tags: git, zsh, alias, upstream-branch

I have this git command that I use a lot as an zsh function.

```
git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

What I want to achive is create an alias and be able to call it as `git upstream` rather than calling just `$ upstream` as an zsh function. The closest I did get was this:

```
[alias]
    upstream = "!fn() { git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) }; fn"
```

However, my guess is, it does fail at `$(...)` due to some parsing error. The error it shows me is this:

```
> git upstream
fn() { git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) }; fn: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is what I am trying to do through aliases possible? If not, can you direct me to any kind of a source to create `git upstream` command?

Comment: create a script `git-upstream`, then when you call `git upstream` this will call `git-upstream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was very close but just missed a semicolon! ‍♂️

```
[alias]
  upstream = "!f() { git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); }; f"
```

Comment: `zsh` allows `f () { cmd }`, but Git doesn't use your login shell; it uses the system default shell, which requires the last command in the body to be properly terminated.

Answer (score 1):

In your local bin directory for example `~/bin`
Create a `git-upstream` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Then make it executable

```
chmod u+x git-upstream
```

Now you can call `git upstream`

Comment: Oh! This is great but how does this work? Does git parses the name after `-` automatically?

Comment: @ogirginc Yes, it does, if you do `git x`, git will look for `git-x`.

Comment: Well, the other way around — git doesn't parse `git-X`, it constructs `git-X` from `git X`.